# Execution of multiple cases within the same switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am looking through someone's C code, and discovered something I didn't even know was possible. Inside some of the cases, the switch variable is modified, with the intention that *another* case is executed after the break.

The switch is inside an interrupt handler, so it will get called repeatedly.

```
switch (variable)
{
    case 1:
        some_code();
        variable = 3;
        break;

    case 2:
        more_code();
        variable = 5;
        break;

    case 3:
        more_code();
        variable = 5;
        break;

    case 4:
        my_code();
        break;

    case 5:
        final_code();
        break;

}
```

The code seems to be working as the author intended.

Is this guaranteed behaviour in C? I always assumed that the break statement would cause execution to jump to directly after the switch statement. I wouldn't have expected it to continue testing every other case.

Comment: It's a fairly common idiom, e.g. for state machines.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common technique for state machine type code. But it doesn't jump automatically like you imagine. The `switch` statement has to be put inside a `while` loop. In this case, I imagine the loop would look something like:

```
while (!done) {
    done = (variable == 5);
    switch (variable) {
    /*...*/
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the `switch` statement could be inside a function body, and that function is called from a loop until the done condition is met.